# Powershell: Filter out specific value from custom output of a program

Tags: powershell, filter

Have a utility program which outputs some data as below format:

```
PS C:\> C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Tools\testApp.exe -i
TestApp version 1.5, Copyright (c) 2021 ABC, Inc.


abcadxx an bn cn id       name           model       xsize   test p/n
======= == == == ==== =============== ============== ======= ==== ==============
   0    09 00 00 73A0 Abc1x          Abc10LX          10000  pass 113-D41LXT-011
```

I want to filter out the value of `name` in this case `Abc1x`
I've tried `Select-Object -Property 'name'` but getting

```
PS C:\> C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Tools\testApp.exe -i | Select-Object -Property 'name'

name
----
```

Tried `ExpandProperty` but that threw error. Since this is a custom output how can I get the value of name?

Comment: It seems like your testApp does not return objects. If your testApp does not offer another output format you will have to parse the output as text.

Comment: is there an option to output a CSV instead of a text table? if so, then you can use the `ConvertFrom-Csv` cmdlet to make it into a PSObject ... and filter FOR [not filter OUT] the name column.

Comment: Ahhh @Lee_Daily, took the words right out of my mouth. Some command line utilities offer a `/Fo CSV` option, to format to a csv. Doing so will allow you to `ConvertFrom-Csv` into *objects* which you can later work with. Otherwise you'll be working with text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What an *external program* outputs is a *stream of text lines (strings)*** from PowerShell's perspective, **not a stream of *objects*** whose properties you can access.

- As the comments note, *if* you can get your external program to output a *structured* text format (via a program-specific parameter), such as CSV, you can let PowerShell convert it to objects via a cmdlet such as [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv), which then enables OO processing.

Absent that, **you need to perform *text parsing***.

- [Avshalom's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68914899/45375) shows how to *transform* the for-display text output to CSV format, which then allows you to parse it into objects.
- If you're only interested in *one* value from the `name` column (the 6th), you can use the following shortcut:

```sh
(-split (C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Tools\testApp.exe -i)[-1])[5]
```

- `(C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Tools\testApp.exe -i)` collects `testApp.exe`'s output lines in an *array* (assuming two or more output lines), and `[-1]` extracts the *last* output line, assumed to contain the data of interest:
- The unary form of the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator splits that line into fields by whitespace, and `[5]` returns the 6th field.

Comment: since I'm only interested in that one value `name`, I went with your shortcut solution and it worked; thanks. I will look into other solutions (Avshalom's) provided if I need them in the future.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @ek777; makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't have your program to test, but just for example:

I converted it to text like this:

```
$text = @"
abcadxx an bn cn id       name           model       xsize   test p/n
======= == == == ==== =============== ============== ======= ==== ==============
   0    09 00 00 73A0 Abc1x          Abc10LX          10000  pass 113-D41LXT-011
"@ -split "\n" ## The split will make it array of lines...
```

Then remove the decorator line `[=======]`:

```
$text = $text | ? {$_ -notmatch "^="}
```

Then replace the white space with commas and get rid of the first comma in the `abcadxx` row as it has two spaces instead of one like all other rows:

```
$text -replace '\s{1,}',',' -replace "^,"
```

So it will look like that:

```
abcadxx,an,bn,cn,id,name,model,xsize,test,p/n,
0,09,00,00,73A0,Abc1x,Abc10LX,10000,pass,113-D41LXT-011
```

Then finally convert it from CSV and select the value of the Name column:

```
$text -replace '\s{1,}',',' -replace "^," | 
ConvertFrom-Csv | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Will show the desirable value:

```
Abc1x
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your app output is purely text, there is no property called name there.

Maybe the Select-String cmdlet can help you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1